# Wave Packets, Group velocity, and Phase velocity

Tags: waves, velocity, dispersion, phase-velocity

Mathematically, you find that the wave function of a particle $\Psi (x,t)$ moves with the same velocity as the velocity of the particle ($v_{particle} = v_{group}$).

Is there a reason why the particle velocity should not equal the phase velocity?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16063/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34214/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36242/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See [this article](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node83.html) for a pretty good description.