# Confused about de Broglie's wavelength

Tags: wave-particle-duality

De Broglie relations state that for frequency $f$ and length $\lambda$ of a matter wave corresponding to (non-relativistic) particle of mass $m$, momentum $p$ and energy $E$ are given by:
$$ \lambda=\frac{h}{p}$$
$$ f=\frac{E}{h}$$
It then follows that 
$$f=\frac{mv^2}{2h}=\frac{mv\cdot v}{2h}=\frac{p\cdot v}{2h}=\frac{h\cdot v}{\lambda\cdot 2h}=\frac{v}{2\lambda}. $$

But for wave with frequency $f$ and length $\lambda$, its speed $v_w$ is equal to
$$ v_w=f\lambda$$ 
hence $$f=\frac{v_w}{\lambda} $$
It would therefore imply that 
$$\frac{v}{2\lambda}=f=\frac{v_w}{\lambda} $$
or $$ v_w=\frac{v}{2}.$$

It would therefore mean that the speed of de Broglie wave corresponding to a particle of speed $v$ would equal $v/2$... Is this correct? Does this make any sense?

Comment: See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/speed-of-a-particle-in-quantum-mechanics-phase-velocity-vs-group-velocity). The answer explains what you have discovered in more detail.

Comment: But is relation $f=\frac{v}{2\lambda}$ , where $f$ is de Brodlie frequency, $\lambda$ wavelength, and $v$ velocity of the corresponding particle right?

Comment: @VanDerWarden It is necessary to understand the group-velocity/phase-velocity distinction to understand this. Duplicate(?): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34214/

Comment: Yes, have a look at the question David suggests: [$\lambda=\frac{2h}{p}$ instead of $\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34214/lambda-frac2hp-instead-of-lambda-frachp) I don't think it's a duplicate of yours but it will certainly you understand what's going on.